# Ajax call in wordpress using action hooks

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm new to wordpress and i wanted to try using ajax calls for some mouse click events. 
I have some basic code to test if it works.
In my plugin file plugin.php

```
function my_scripts() {
  $plugin_url = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ );
  wp_register_script('search-filter',$plugin_url .  'js/search-filter.js',array(), filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) .  'js/search-filter.js' ));
  wp_localize_script( 'search-filter', 'my_ajax_call', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')) );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'search-filter');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
function myAjaxHanlder(){
  var_dump("THIS IS A TEST");
  echo '<script>console.log("MY AJAX HANDLER")</script>';
}
add_action('wp_ajax_hello_world', 'myAjaxHanlder' );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_hello_world', 'myAjaxHanlder' );
```

and in my javascript file search-filter.js

```
(function($){

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".search-hits").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // var gender = $("#gender").val()||[];
        // var brand =$("#brand").val() || [];
        // var color =$("#color").val() || [];
        // var gender_JSON = JSON.stringify(gender);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            crossDomain : true,
            url: my_ajax_call.ajax_url,
            data: {action:'hello_world', query:"nike"},
            success: function(response){
                alert(response);
            }

            });
       });
   });

})(jQuery);
```

I'm able to send the data using ajax, but the function myAjaxHanlder is not getting executed.

Comment: Get rid of this line `var_dump("THIS IS A TEST");` and return some json stuff or you really want to `alert('<script>console.log("MY AJAX HANDLER")</script>';)`?

Comment: I had that in just to test if the function was getting called. Purely for debugging purposes

Comment: I think you should return some value from 'myAjaxHanlder' function and also add wp_die() at end of function.

Comment: Also you try something like this  :                                                                    
 if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        /**
         * Fires authenticated AJAX actions for logged-in users.
         */
   
    add_action('wp_ajax_hello_world', 'myAjaxHanlder' );
} else {
        /**
         * Fires non-authenticated AJAX actions for logged-out users.
         */
   add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_hello_world', 'myAjaxHanlder' );
}

Comment: Your `myAjaxHandler() ` should not "return" anything.  It needs to echo some output and `die()` (normally, using [wp_send_json](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_send_json) which automatically `die`s.  Without `die`, you will get the dreaded WP `0` response), and it _must_ contain a "die" statement.  Additionally, change `alert(response);` to `console.log(response)` - alert can't handle objects, the console shows the full structure of the response.  Learn to use your brower's developer tools, specifically the "network" tab, which will let you troubleshoot AJAX effectively.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're approaching it incorrectly, and WP handles Ajax differently. Your Ajax handler function should be included in both hooks (for the admin and front-end) like so:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_hello_world', 'hello_world' );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_hello_world', 'hello_world' );
```

The handler function name has to be used on your Ajax call as well (which you've done):

```
data: {action:'hello_world' ...
```

It also has to echo a response and then die. I recommend using WP's implementation of `die()` :

```
wp_die();
```

Here is what I reworked, hopefully it helps:

```js
function hello_world(){
  var_dump("THIS IS A TEST");

  echo '<script>console.log("MY AJAX HANDLER")</script>';

  // OR

  echo $_POST['query'];
  
  wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_hello_world', 'hello_world' );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_hello_world', 'hello_world' );
```

Codex has more info: [Ajax on WP Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Comment: I made the wp_die() change. It still doesn't fire the function. :(

Comment: @nash63 did you change both `add_action` to include `hello_world` and rename `myAjaxHanlder` to `hello_world` as well? As shown in the answer

Comment: Just to make sure - your PHP is on a different domain and `url` correctly points to it (since you have `crossDomain` set to true)? On chrome Network tab, can you see the ajax fire with a 200? There are so many variables but I'd first check your server log for PHP errors and monitor Network tab for Ajax calls.

Comment: I did check the network tab... it gives me 200 success. The ajax call works but only the function doesn't fire for some reason

Comment: Do you mind updating your question with the updated code?